# How to set multiple colors of different parameters in email sent from C# project

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, email, colors

I want to set the color of my text of the email which generate email by collecting data from different objects and parameters. I have code it but unable to set individual color of my context of each parameter

My code is given:

```
SmtpClient emailClient = new SmtpClient();

            MailMessage emailMessage = new MailMessage();
            emailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;


                sbEmailBody.AppendLine("[" + **test.GetType().Name** + "]");
```

How can I set color of **test.GetType().Name** parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

append the html text like this

```
<span style="color:red">My Text"</span>
```

as in your example

```
foreach (ITest test in tests)
{
  sbEmailBody.AppendLine("<span style='color:red'>[" + **test.GetType().Name** + "]</span>");
}
```